# How to blockquote separate paragraphs only once?

Tags: support, markdown, blockquote

For want of efficiency, I prefer not to type `>` in front of each disjoint paragraph. So how would I blockquote B, C, D in the following? Thanks.

**Update:** Does user Fish Below the Ice's Answer only help when spacing doesn't matter?

(a) CORRECT. The reference to the end of the Eastern Bloc is preceded by the 
statement that: ‘Four years in the C20 would be considered relatively quick for
the weakening of an established order’. The end of the Eastern Bloc is used as
an example of that fact and a comparison is made to what was achieved in four
years in the 16th century.
(b) INCORRECT. See (a).
(c) INCORRECT. No comparison is made of the two regimes.

With that user's method, then the above would lose its spaces and become, unwantedly:

> (a) CORRECT. The reference to the end of the Eastern Bloc is preceded
>   by the  statement that: ‘Four years in the C20 would be considered
>   relatively quick for the weakening of an established order’. The end
>   of the Eastern Bloc is used as an example of that fact and a
>   comparison is made to what was achieved in four years in the 16th
>   century.    (b) INCORRECT. See (a).    (c) INCORRECT. No comparison is
>   made of the two regimes.

Comment: Hm, I'd say that's a bug. It shouldn't remove all the line-breaks you had entered like that when you format it as a blockquote. However, if they were formatted as separate paragraphs (blank line between each one), the button would work correctly and blockquote each line for you.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the most efficient way is to write out your paragraphs as you would, select all the text you want to blockquote, and then click the "Blockquote" button in the editor. (Or, even more efficiently, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>.)

That'll put the `>` Markdown blockquote indicator in front of every line for you.

This also re-formats a bit, so if you want to maintain your paragraphs, make sure there's a blank line between each one.

Comment: +1. Would you please see my emended OP?

Answer (score 1):

No trivial way, but you can just use HTML:

```
A 

<blockquote>
<p>B</p>

<p>C</p>

<p>D</p>
</blockquote>
```

Output:

A

> B
>
> C
>
> D

As you see, the downside is that you'll have to wrap each paragraph with `<p>` and `</p>` tags.